# WM_XBUTTONDOWN return value difference between ATL/MSDN documented value?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, atl, wtl

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646245(v=vs.85).aspx, I extract that:

> If an application processes this message, it should return TRUE. For
>   more information about processing the return value, see the Remarks
>   section.

In case that matters, the same holds for `WM_XBUTTONUP` and `WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK`.

I expected that I would find `MSG_WM_XBUTTONDOWN` to do exactly this. However, in `atlcrack.h` from Chromium (https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/third_party/wtl/include/atlcrack.h) , I find the following:

```
// void OnXButtonDown(int fwButton, int dwKeys, CPoint ptPos)
#define MSG_WM_XBUTTONDOWN(func) \
    if (uMsg == WM_XBUTTONDOWN) \
    { \
        SetMsgHandled(TRUE); \
        func(GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam), GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(wParam), _WTYPES_NS::CPoint(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam))); \
        lResult = 0; \
        if(IsMsgHandled()) \
            return TRUE; \
    }
```

Similar pieces can be found for `MSG_WM_XBUTTONDOWN` and `MSG_WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK`.

In this snippet, the line `lResult = 0` confuses me. Shouldn't it be `lResult = TRUE` (according to the MSDN)?

Comment: There is a `return TRUE;` statement.

Comment: I see, but as far as I understand the MSDN, the return value refers to `func` (the callback) and not the the function which uses `MSG_WM_XBUTTONDOWN` (i.e. not the `MSG_MAP`). If you have a look at the respective pages concerning `WM_MOUSEMOVE` resp. `MSG_WM_MOUSEMOVE`, you see a similar pattern. `MSG_WM_MOUSEMOVE` also returns `TRUE`, and the MSDN states that the callback shall return `0` (which, in the case of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is imho properly reflected by `lResult = 0`).

Comment: The MSDN does not document the WTL. WTL is not officially supported.

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste bug from the other mouse message crackers.  It just doesn't matter that much, this message is normally posted with PostMessage() so there isn't anybody around to see the wrong LRESULT.  Unless somebody is simulating input, then they're kinda screwed, maybe.  Just file a bug with the Chromium project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in WTL that has been [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/wtl/bugs/284/).